# How can I set log file max size on android

Tags: android, logging

I'm using microlog4android to log to file. The question is how can set maximum file size?

microlog4android FileAppender class has two methods: getLogSize (which always return -1 ) and clear. I could clear log when it reaches certain size but getLogSize doesn't seem to work.

Is there any better, more mature android logging solution that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[logback-android](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/)** with the [`RollingFileAppender`](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/doc/1.0.0-4/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) and [`SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy`](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/doc/1.0.0-4/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html), but you should be aware of a [bug](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCORE-123) ([src](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.java#L57)) that may cause your working log file to exceed the max file size. A workaround is to subclass the triggering policy to bypass the bug:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import ch.qos.logback.core.util.FileSize;

public class SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<E> extends ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(final File activeFile, final E event) {
        return (activeFile.length() >= FileSize.valueOf(getMaxFileSize()).getSize());
    }
}
```

Here's an example config (based on the Logback [manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy) and including the workaround above) that you can put into your AndroidManifest.xml. I tested this in Android 4.0.3 emulator, but I imagine it would also work in earlier versions.

```
<logback>
    <configuration debug="true">
        <appender
                name="LOGCAT"
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender" >
            <encoder>
                <pattern>[%method] %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <property name="dest.dir" value="/sdcard/test/" />
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${dest.dir}/test.log</file>
            <append>false</append>

            <!-- #########################################
                 # Max of 2 backup zip's (plus uncompressed
                 # working file, ${dest.dir}/test.log)
                 ######################################### -->
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${dest.dir}/test.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
                <minIndex>1</minIndex>
                <maxIndex>2</maxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>

            <!-- #########################################
                 # Rollover when file size reaches 5MB. 
                 # We're using our custom policy here that
                 # works around a bug (LBCORE-123).
                 ######################################### -->
            <!--<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">-->
            <triggeringPolicy class="com.example.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <logger name="com.example.HelloAndroidActivity" level="TRACE">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </logger>

        <root level="DEBUG" >
            <appender-ref ref="LOGCAT" />
        </root>
    </configuration>
</logback>
```

Comment: very good information. Somehow after I do what you said above, I still could not get the file rolling. I put a break point at SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy<E>, and I could get call back, and return would be true. However file is not rolling. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use normal File apis to retrieve file length and then delete/rename it  before initializing Logger if it exceeds size limit.