# Log4j Implementation in Android

Tags: android, logging, log4j, android-logcat

I am new to android development.I want to write logs to one file in SD Card.How can i do this using Log4j.What all are the steps to Implement Log4j.I read many atricles.But none of them describing how to configure and implement it.Can anyone please explain how to do this in android in simple words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should look at [`logback`](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/) (the next generation of log4j). Use the [`FileAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) or [`RollingFileAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender).

### Instructions:

1. Add `slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar` and `logback-android-1.0.6-2.jar` to your classpath.
2. Create the file `assets/logback.xml` in your project (or use the `AndroidManifest.xml`...see [example](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/)), containing the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/sdcard/testFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
        
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

*Note: Since the specified path is on SD, make sure to use [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission. You can instead specify a different path where you already have write permissions.*

Your Java code, which contains the SLF4J logging calls, now logs all events at or above the `DEBUG` level to the `/sdcard/testFile.log`.

### Example Java:

```
package com.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.example.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    static private final Logger LOG =
                       LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloAndroidActivity.class);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       
       //
       // Based on the configuration above, these log statements
       // are written to /sdcard/testFile.log
       //
       LOG.info("Hello Android!");
       LOG.debug("reply: {}", Example.hello());
    }
}

class Example {
    static private final Logger LOG =
                     LoggerFactory.getLogger(Example.class);

    static public String hello() {
        LOG.trace("entered hello()");
        return "Hi there!";
    }
}
```

Comment: @user46874...thanks..it is working..I have one more doubt..is it possible to specify size of Log file?So that after exceeding this size it will create an new log file with different name...If it possible where i need to configure it??

Comment: Yes, you need to use the `RollingFileAppender` with the `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy`. See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8721176/1200334) to a similar question.

Comment: I know this is old, but..

Is it possible to have multiple output logs? How would you set that up?

Comment: Yes. Create multiple `<appender>` elements and include them in the `root` logger with `<appender-ref>` (see [example](http://pastebin.com/pMYnfhg9)).