# On Android, what can logcat log? What cannot?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Not quite clear what logcat can and cann't. Suppose my phone is connected to my local computer. Do:

c:> adb shell logcat > /data/tmp/logs/log.txt

log.txt file will be created on the android devie. After some time, phone crashes. How can I got the log.txt back from the device? Is there a way to directly output all the events (even kernel message such as dmesg does) on the device to my computer, instead of generating a log file on the device first, then pull it to the computer?

Answer (score 1):

You Should use **android-logging-log4j.jar**

You can store all the log in .txt or .xml
For More details go through

https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/

You need to give path where you want to save your log. So can navigate to that path and can get the log file

Hope this help.

Comment: [`logback-android`](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/) is a more advanced alternative than `android-logging-log4j`. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826025/log4j-implementation-in-android